# How do I modify a file without updating the modification time?

Tags: timestamps

Sometimes I want to make a minor edit to a text file (e.g., fix a typo), but I want to keep its modification time unchanged. (Motivation: modtime is useful for listing directories in chronological order, for telling when a file's content was last *substantively* updated, etc. I don't want a trivial edit to obliterate this information.)

This is certainly possible: Unix allows me to manually set the modtime to anything I want (this does set the ctime to the present, which is fine by me). E.g., with `touch -t <time>`, or with the `utimes(2)` system call. This question is about **a simple way to edit a file and then set the modification time to *exactly* what it was before editing.** I am mainly interested in solutions that are editor-agnostic, i.e., if emacs has a `save-file-no-update-mtime` command, that's interesting but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks! The linked question is tagged [vim], but the solutions are indeed editor-independent. IMHO the question hasn't been fully answered, though (`touch -r` is clever, but using a temporary file is clunky...)

Comment: yeah most answers there are editor-agnostic but _Shâu Shắc_'s solution doesn't use a temporary file (it's `gnu` specific though)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fairly simple solution, based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43120/23344) to the related question discovered by @don_crissti. But I was hoping for something that doesn't use an extra file-- can anyone do better?

```
touch -r some-file.txt .timestamp 
emacs some-file.txt  # Or whatever
touch -r .timestamp some-file.txt 
rm .timestamp
```